# How to successfully drive a MassTransitStateMachine via the InMemoryTestHarness?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, state, masstransit, automatonymous

Following up to: [How to write MassTransitStateMachine unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763600/how-to-write-masstransitstatemachine-unit-tests)

Here's a simple test class (using MS Test) for a simple state machine called `ProcedureStateMachine` (note: this is not a real production state machine for us... just an experiment I'd used to play around with `MassTransitStateMachine` a while back..  it seemed a handy self-contained place to experiment with getting unit testing going too):

```
[TestClass]
public class ProcedureStateMachineTests
{
    private ProcedureStateMachine _machine;
    private InMemoryTestHarness _harness;
    private StateMachineSagaTestHarness<ProcedureContext, ProcedureStateMachine> _saga;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _machine = new ProcedureStateMachine();
        _harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
        _saga = _harness.StateMachineSaga<ProcedureContext, ProcedureStateMachine>(_machine);

        _harness.Start().Wait();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _harness.Stop().Wait();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task That_Can_Start()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Act
        await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new BeginProcessing
        {
            ProcedureId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Steps = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C" }
        });

        // Assert
        var sagaContext = _saga.Created.First();
        sagaContext.Saga.RemainingSteps.ShouldHaveCountOf(2);
    }
}
```

And here's the state machine class itself:

```
public class ProcedureStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<ProcedureContext>
{
    public State Processing { get; private set; }
    public State Cancelling { get; private set; }
    public State CompleteOk { get; private set; }
    public State CompleteError { get; private set; }
    public State CompleteCancelled { get; private set; }

    public Event<BeginProcessing> Begin { get; private set; }
    public Event<StepCompleted> StepDone { get; private set; }
    public Event<CancelProcessing> Cancel { get; private set; }
    public Event<FinalizeProcessing> Finalize { get; private set; }

    public ProcedureStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => Begin);
        Event(() => StepDone);
        Event(() => Cancel);
        Event(() => Finalize);

        BeforeEnterAny(binder => binder
            .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                $"ENTERING STATE [{context.Data.Name}]")));

        Initially(
            When(Begin)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.RemainingSteps = new Queue<string>(context.Data.Steps);
                })
                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                    $"EVENT [{nameof(Begin)}]: Procedure [{context.Data.ProcedureId}] Steps [{string.Join(",", context.Data.Steps)}]"))
                .Publish(context => new ExecuteStep
                {
                    ProcedureId = context.Instance.CorrelationId,
                    StepId = context.Instance.RemainingSteps.Dequeue()
                })
                .Publish(context => new SomeFunMessage
                {
                    CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId,
                    TheMessage = $"Procedure [{context.Data.CorrelationId} has begun..."
                })
                .TransitionTo(Processing)
            );

        During(Processing,
            When(StepDone)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    if (null == context.Instance.AccumulatedResults)
                    {
                        context.Instance.AccumulatedResults = new List<StepResult>();
                    }
                    context.Instance.AccumulatedResults.Add(
                        new StepResult
                        {
                            CorrelationId = context.Instance.CorrelationId,
                            StepId = context.Data.StepId,
                            WhatHappened = context.Data.WhatHappened
                        });
                })
                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                    $"EVENT [{nameof(StepDone)}]: Procedure [{context.Data.ProcedureId}] Step [{context.Data.StepId}] Result [{context.Data.WhatHappened}] RemainingSteps [{string.Join(",", context.Instance.RemainingSteps)}]"))
                .If(context => !context.Instance.RemainingSteps.Any(),
                    binder => binder.TransitionTo(CompleteOk))
                .If(context => context.Instance.RemainingSteps.Any(),
                    binder => binder.Publish(context => new ExecuteStep
                    {
                        ProcedureId = context.Instance.CorrelationId,
                        StepId = context.Instance.RemainingSteps.Dequeue()
                    })),
            When(Cancel)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.RemainingSteps.Clear();
                })
                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                    $"EVENT [{nameof(Cancel)}]: Procedure [{context.Data.ProcedureId}] will be cancelled with following steps remaining [{string.Join(",", context.Instance.RemainingSteps)}]"))
                .TransitionTo(Cancelling)
            );

        During(Cancelling,
            When(StepDone)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.SomeStringValue = "Booo... we cancelled...";
                })
                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                    $"EVENT [{nameof(StepDone)}]: Procedure [{context.Data.ProcedureId}] Step [{context.Data.StepId}] completed while cancelling."))
                .TransitionTo(CompleteCancelled));

        During(CompleteOk, When(Finalize).Finalize());
        During(CompleteCancelled, When(Finalize).Finalize());
        During(CompleteError, When(Finalize).Finalize());

        // The "SetCompleted*" thing is what triggers purging of the state context info from the store (eg. Redis)...  without that, the 
        // old completed state keys will gradually accumulate and dominate the Redis store.
        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }
}
```

When debug this test, the `_harness` has the `BeginProcessing` message in its `Sent` collection, but there's nothing in the `_saga.Created` collection. It seems like I'm missing some plumbing to cause the harness to actually drive the state machine when the messages are sent?

====

Removing the `.Wait()` calls from `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` and updating the test to the following does NOT change the behavior:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task That_Can_Start()
    {
        try
        {
            await _harness.Start();
            // Arrange

            // Act
            await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new BeginProcessing
            {
                ProcedureId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Steps = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"}
            });

            // Assert
            var sagaContext = _saga.Created.First();
            sagaContext.Saga.RemainingSteps.ShouldHaveCountOf(3);
        }
        finally
        {
            await _harness.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider keeping the code async and not calling blocking calls `.Wait()`. Update setup and tear down to async Tasks and await `_harness.Start()` and `_harness.Stop()` could be experiencing a deadlock cause of the mixing of async and blocking calls.

Comment: I tried that originally and was getting the following error: `Method HappyFunTests.HelloTests.ProcedureStateMachineTests.SetUp has wrong signature. The method must be non-static, public, does not return a value and should not take any parameter.`  (i.e. the MSTest [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] attributes prevent me from making the methods `async Task`)

Comment: check this work around for the test initialize https://stackoverflow.com/a/20510792/5233410

Comment: You can tty using `TaskUtil.Await(Func<Task> action)` from MassTransit instead of `Wait()`. I use it in my test (last in the list in the original question).

Comment: Same issue (whether I use `.Wait()`, or `TaskUtil.Wait(...)`, or move everything into the test and do the `try - finally` trick so I can use `await`.  I think the `_harness.Start()` is being called in all cases, and running to completion (assuming that each one of these approaches is valid for waiting until the harness has been Started). I do not think this is a deadlock around `_harness.Start()` as the actual test code executes and `.Send(..)` actually puts something into the harness' `Sent` collection. It's seems like something's needed to get harness to deliver that to the state machine?

Comment: I know you've looked at a lot of unit tests, make sure you've looked at this one since it actually checks the `Created` collection to ensure it contains the saga. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration.Tests/Testing_Specs.cs#L25

Comment: Thanks Chris! The saga is definitely not being created in my test for some reason. I've taken the tests you referenced and I'm running those in my project via MSTest now...  they pass (awesome)..  so now I'm incrementally morphing the passing ones towards the complexity of my test to see when things break.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - Interesting...  when I switch the `Instance.CurrentState` property to be a `string` (we're using `SagaRedisEntity` and for some reason I'm remembering that did not support `State` as the type here), the `Should_handle_the_stop_state` test intermittently fails, not making it to the `Final` state by the time the `Assert.AreEqual` happens. There appears to be a race condition here. I'm still investigating, but something already seems off.

Comment: Totally a race condition...  if I add `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));` to my failing test between the `await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send` and the assertion, the saga is now created by the time the test code tries to get it and assert..   Are there util / extensions around waiting for the harness to finish processing so test code can know when it's safe to begin their assert phase?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - Heads-up - I've posted how I worked around the race condition below. If you guys have intermittently failing tests around the Sagas, this might be what's going on, though I saw that it was unlikely to happen when the `CurrentState` property was of Type `State` rather than `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the test code as shown above was suffering from a race condition between the `_harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send` operation and some asynchronous (beyond what await on the `Send` waits for) behavior in the `StateMachineSagaTestHarness`. As a result, the "Assert" phase of the test code was executing before the saga had been created and allowed to handle the sent message.

Digging into the `SagaTestHarness` code a bit, I found a few helper methods that I was able to use to wait until certain conditions on the saga are met. The methods are:

```
/// <summary>
/// Waits until a saga exists with the specified correlationId
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sagaId"></param>
/// <param name="timeout"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<Guid?> Exists(Guid sagaId, TimeSpan? timeout = null)

/// <summary>
/// Waits until at least one saga exists matching the specified filter
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter"></param>
/// <param name="timeout"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<IList<Guid>> Match(Expression<Func<TSaga, bool>> filter, TimeSpan? timeout = null)

/// <summary>
/// Waits until the saga matching the specified correlationId does NOT exist
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sagaId"></param>
/// <param name="timeout"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<Guid?> NotExists(Guid sagaId, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
```

So I settled on using things like `await _saga.Match(s => null != s.RemainingSteps);` and such to effectively duplicate my later asserts and wait either until the timeout (default is 30 seconds) or the later-asserted condition has become true (and therefore safe to Assert against).. whichever comes first.

This will get me unstuck for now until I can think of a better way to know when the harness is "caught up" and ready to be interrogated.

Comment: I am running into issues where `await _saga.Match(...)` doesn't seem to match final saga states (or perhaps anything that should happen to the state machine instance after the first message is processed by the state machine?). I'm still digging, but so far, these methods haven't been the total solution.